# Why isn't Unreal Engine 5 widget mode allowing me to put in new text or change the color or change the wording of the widget?

Tags: unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

Why isn't Unreal Engine 5 widget mode allowing me to put in new text or change the color or change the wording of the widget?

[image]

I'm here to make it work again for me.

Answer (score 1):

You used the [property binding](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/property-binding-for-umg-in-unreal-engine/) feature in UMG which allows you to assign functions or properties to parts of your user interface.

Your details panel is not wide enough to show all the information, that's why you can only see the bound function. If you drag it a little, you see three elements next to each other:

1. The property input field (the `Text` input for "Text" or the `LinearColor` previewer for "Color and Opacity")
2. The currently bound function
3. The bind dropdown that gives you more options on what to bind or to remove the current binding

If you want to change the value for the preview, you can change it using the property input field (as soon, as it becomes visible). If you want to change the value at runtime (with property binding), you have to go into the function that is bound and change the return value. If you want to be able to set the value at runtime using a `Set`-node, you have to remove the binding first.

But one word of advise here: Property binding is not good practise. It is usually better to set the value when the value to show actually changes using [delegates](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/ActorCommunication/EventDispatcherQuickStart/).

References (and good resources for UMG in general):

- [Unreal UI Best Practices](https://benui.ca/unreal/ui-best-practices/#dont-use-bind-variable) by Ben UI
- [UMG-Slate-Compendium](https://github.com/YawLighthouse/UMG-Slate-Compendium#cpu-considerations) by YawLighthouse